# VSync disabled in games after an upgrade to 23.10

Tags: drivers, nvidia, games

i just updated to mantic minotaur and after the installation of required drivers (nvidia-driver-535) i launched a game, with enabled vertical synchronization, and i quickly noticed that vsync wasn't working even though it was enabled. i can't find any information on how to do fix it on Linux online. my current gpu is Nvidia geforce gtx 970 4gb. edit: found fix in related questions right after i posted, i will try to follow steps in this question, but if it won't i will downgrade my system.